# What is the polynomial satisfying $(t,t^2,t^3)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, analytic-geometry, real-algebraic-geometry

What is the equation satisfying the parameterized equation $(t,t^2,t^3)$ where $t$ is a real constant?

Comment: this is a very famous example called the twisted cubic http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twisted_cubic

Comment: err, unless i'm misinterpreting this, because saying that's the parametrisation of the equation and also $t$ is a real constant is confusing

Comment: I'm more confused than anyone. How is $(t,t^2,t^3)$ an equation and how do you satisfy it?

Comment: @RahulNarain i believe what is meant is that you have the map $t \mapsto (t, t^2, t^3)$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$, and we're after a single polynomial which vanishes only on the image. in general it might be the intersection of the roots of a bunch of polynomials, but over nonalgebraically closed fields you can get away with just *one*

Comment: A single polynomial? In how many variables? For example, $$yz-x^5\in\Bbb R[x,y,z]\;$ ...?$$

Comment: That doesn't work, @DonAntonio, because $y=32$, $z=1$, $x=2$ is a solution to that equation, but is not on that curve. I believe algebraic number theory pretty much ensures the only "single equation" solution is the sum of squares of polynomials being equal to zero - basically, the combination of single equations into one equation.

Comment: The title's question only asks for (the) polynomial that vanishes on $\;\{(t,t^2,t^3)\;;\;t\in\Bbb R\}\,$ . The above one makes the cut. I suppose though, that this question is somehow related to algebraic geometry and perhaps it is *the ideal* of an algebraic variety what is being searched...Of course, the complete ideal for in the corresponding affine space is generated by two or three (can't remember right now)different polynomials in three variables...but that wasn't asked.

Comment: Ah, depends on what is meant by "satisfying," but yeah, I guess you are right. I doubt is is really looking for an algebraic geometry solution, but that is the heart of the problem, I think. @DonAntonio

Comment: Me too, @Thomas Andrews. Let us wait until the OP clear this up...\

Answer (score 6):

How about something as simple as:

$$(y-x^2)^2 + (z-x^3)^2 = 0$$

This sort of sum of squares is just a trick, a way to combine two equations into one, and it only works when $x,y,z$ are confined to the real numbers - if you wanted complex numbers, you'd have to stick with the combination of two equations.